# LNK1561 FATAL ERROR with VS express 2012

Tags: c++

I'm using visual studio express 2012 and getting the fatal error message..

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;
      int Main()
{
   double TotalProfit,
        yearlysales = 8600000,
        percentsales = 0.58;

   TotalProfit = yearlysales * percentsales;

  cout << "Total Profit for the year is $" << TotalProfit << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. The program entry point should be called `main`, not `Main`

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
int main()
```

instead of

```
int Main()
```

reason for this is because C++ is **case-sensitive**.

Let's take the following example:

**What would you do if you wanted to print the following variable?**

```
int k = 0;
```

would you do:

```
std::cout << K;
```

**No!** Because K is a completely different variable than k, K is undefined.

---

Also:

I noticed in your code you have the following:

```
yearlysales = 8600000,
```

I won't tell you the specific error, I want you to find it out.

The other variable deceleration is correct:

```
percentsales = 0.58;
```

Comment: No problem. Its my pleasure.